# How to specify which page js module is included on

Tags: magento2, module, javascript

I am following this tutorial https://devdocs.magento.com/videos/fundamentals/add-a-javascript-module/ At the end of the tutorial it says
`Now we’ll go to any product view page, and we should see the “HELLO WORLD!” message.`

To get a better understanding of how modules work, I would like to view the "HELLO WORLD!" message on a different page. What would I change to view the alert on a different page.

[I read](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/architecture/archi_perspectives/components/modules/mod_and_areas.html#note-about-magento-request-processing)

> The frontName is a value defined in the module. Using
> catalog/product/view as an example:
>
> - catalog is the frontName in the module area’s routes.xml file
> - product is in the controller folder
> - view is the controller class

I thought that I could change the filename catalog_product_view.xml to catalog_product_compare.xml to view the "HELLO WORLD!" alert on the compare page instead, since compare is a class listed as a [catalog controller](https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/2.4/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Controller/Product)

How would I choose which page I see a "HELLO WORLD!" alert on?

Documentation that helped me understand the answers:

- [data-mage-init is used to insert a JS module inside a phtml template](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js_init.html#init_phtml)
- [page layout documentation to understand how templates are merged](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript called from line:

```
<div data-mage-init='{"hello": {"message": "HELLO WORLD!"}}'>
```

And that in inside file :

```
app/code/Learning/Js/view/frontend/templates/hello.phtml
```

And this template file is include from this layout file

```
app/code/Learning/Js/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml
```

So if you want to check you check open this in browser like:

```
www.domain.com/catalog/product/view/id/xxx
```

So here xxx is product_id that is required paramerter for view controller class / or you can directly open any product from category page then you can see.

So if you want to to see in compare page compare url is :

```
www.domain.com/catalog/product_compare/
```

or can say

```
www.domain.com/catalog/product_compare/index
```

Because index is default taken if you not pass controller class in url
So for that layout file is :

> catalog_product_compare_index.xml

Answer (score 1):

You could include the javascript on the page that you want catalog_product_compare.xml or catalog_product_view.xml. if you want include the script on all catalog product controllers, you can use Magento_Catalog/layout/default.xml

It is hard to say how to choose which file you must to change, since it depends on the goal.